# How to assign a value that changes if the given if statements are true or false

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a code that counts if the statements are true and assigns a value to every "true" if statement.
For example, if the first statement is true, I need to assign A. If the next statement is false, skip. If the next statement is true, assign B. And so on.

I already tried placing it in for loop but I am not getting the desired result.

```
public virtual void AssignEnabledOptions()
    {
        int iBtnCount = 0;
        string sVar1, sVar2, sVar3, sVar4, sVar5, sVar6;

        sVar1 = "2";
        sVar2 = "1";
        sVar3 = "1";
        sVar4 = "1";
        sVar5 = "0";
        sVar6 = "1";


        if (sVar1.Value.Equals("1") || sVar1.Value.Equals("2"))
            iBtnCount = iBtnCount + 1; // if true, assign A
        if (sVar2.Value.Equals("1"))
            iBtnCount = iBtnCount + 1; // if true, assign B, if false, assign B to next true statement
        if (sVar3.Value.Equals("1") || sVar3.Value.Equals("2"))
            iBtnCount = iBtnCount + 1;
        if (sVar4.Value.Equals("1"))
            iBtnCount = iBtnCount + 1;
        if (sVar5.Value.Equals("1"))
            iBtnCount = iBtnCount + 1;
        if (sVar6.Value.Equals("1"))
            iBtnCount = iBtnCount + 1;
    }
```

Based on the data above, I expect the output:

```
sVar1 = A
sVar2 = B
sVar3 = C
sVar4 = D
sVar5 = None
sVar6 = E
```

And so on..

Comment: what is `Variables`?

Comment: I have edited my code @sohaib

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way to do this it sVar s are individual variables. If they are stored in a list or array for list you can do something like this:

```
int iBtnCount = 0;
//string[] sVars = { sVar1, sVar2, sVar3, sVar4, sVar5, sVar6 };
string[][] possibleValues =
{
    new string[]{ "1", "2" },
    new string[]{ "1" },
    new string[]{ "1", "2" },
    new string[]{ "1" },
    new string[]{ "1" },
    new string[]{ "1" },
};

for(int i = 0; i < sVars.Length; i++)
{
    if(possibleValues[i].Contains(sVars[i]))
    {
        sVars[i] = ((char)('A' + iBtnCount++)).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        sVars[i] = "None";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Class for assigning next letter if condition is true:

```
public class Assigner : IDisposable
{
    private char _current;

    public bool CheckAndAssign(Predicate<string> condition, ref string sVar)
    {            
        if (condition(sVar))
        {
            if (_current == default(char))
            {
                _current = 'A'                    
            }
            else
            {
                _current++;
            }

            sVar = _current.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            sVar = "None"
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _current = default(char);
    }
}
```

Call for example:

```
using(var assigner = new Assigner())
{
    assigner.CheckAndAssign(x => x.Equals("1") || x.Equals("2"), ref sVar1);
    // etc.
}
```

Сan also be used in a loop and in any way.

Answer (score 0):

```
list[i] = ((char)(letter + iBtnCount)).ToString();
```

This will give you next character correctly.

```
private void AssignEnabledOptions()
    {
        int iBtnCount = 0;
        string sVar1, sVar2, sVar3, sVar4, sVar5, sVar6;
        char letter = 'A';

        sVar1 = "2";
        sVar2 = "1";
        sVar3 = "1";
        sVar4 = "1";
        sVar5 = "0";
        sVar6 = "1";

        List<string> list = new List<string>
        {
            sVar1,
            sVar2,
            sVar3,
            sVar4,
            sVar5,
            sVar6
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(list[i]) > 0)
            {
                list[i] = ((char)(letter + iBtnCount)).ToString();
                iBtnCount = iBtnCount + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                list[i] = "None";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are unclear.
However, the key concept you should understand is that you can perform math operations on characters

```
char myLetter = 'A';
myLetter++; //now myLetter == 'B'
```

Here's one possible implementation, but it really should be made more generic than this depending on what your real goal is.

```
    void AssignEnabledOptions()
    {
        string[] options = {"2", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1"};
        bool one(string s) => s == "1";
        bool oneOrTwo(string s) => s == "1" || s == "2";

        var predicates = new List<Func<string, bool>> {oneOrTwo, one, oneOrTwo, one, one, one};

        var results = options.Zip(predicates, (s, pred) => pred(s));
        char character = 'A';
        var resultCharacters = results.Select(b => b ? character++.ToString() : null);
    }
```